# Define style and custom attribute in View instead of xml

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I want to implement custom style for view. Let's take an example of button. Some common values will be shared across the app for that I am using style like below:

```
<style name="Widget.Demo.Button.Primary" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">64dp</item>
        <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.Demo.GrayPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.Demo.GrayPrimary" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/gray</item>
</style>
```

Now I want to add some of the custom attribute in the button like below (This is just an example not the real attribute):

```
     <com.android.CustomButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/first"
        app:abc="primary"
        style="@style/Widget.Demo.Button.Primary"/>

attrs.xml:

<declare-styleable name="CustomButtonAttr" >
        <attr name="abc" format="enum" >
            <enum name="primary" value="1"/>
            <enum name="secondary" value="2"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

I don't want to define style and custom attribute in xml everytime. Is there any way to get custom attribute directly in my customview and `Widget.Demo.Button.Primary` set by default in my below class?

```
class CustomButton : MaterialButton {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(
        ThemeEnforcement.createThemedContext(context, attributeSet, 0, 0),
        attributeSet,
       0
    )
}
```

I don't want to define style in xml for every button or view which I create. So is there a way to define in `CustomButton` class along with custom attributes ? If yes could you please give me some references.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can use the default style attribute in the constructor.

Define a new attribute:

```xml
<attr name="customButtonStyle" format="reference" />
```

Then use the appropriate view constructor:

```kotlin
private val defStyleAttr = R.attr.customButtonStyle

class CustomButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : MaterialButton(
    ThemeEnforcement.createThemedContext(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr, 0),
    attributeSet,
    defStyleAttr
) {

    init {
        val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.CustomButton, 
            defStyleAttr,
            0
        )
        ...
    
}
```

In your theme, point `customButtonStyle` to the style resource that you want used by default:

```xml
<style name="Theme.Demo" parent="Base.Theme.Demo">
    <item name="customButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Demo.Button.Primary</item>
</style>
```

Note that `android:theme` should be changed to `materialThemeOverlay` in that style resource, as it won't be applied when read from a default style. As you're already wrapping the context with the `ThemeEnforcement` function (newer versions of Material Design Components change this to `MaterialThemeOverlay`), this custom view supports `materialThemeOverlay`

---

You can add your custom attributes to the style too:

```xml
<style name="Widget.Demo.Button.Primary" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="abc">primary</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">64dp</item>
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Demo.GrayPrimary</item>
</style>
```

---

[Reference (blog + video)](https://ataulm.com/2020/05/07/refactoring-themes-with-style-default-styles.html)

Comment: This works as I wanted to but is there any way that I can club the custom attribute in style as well instead of defining in every place ?

Comment: yep, just stick it in the style too. Edited the answer.

Comment: BTW since it's a custom view, you could just set the primary mode in the `init` function?

Comment: nope, this is how all native and MDC widgets work too